# How to add onload to an onchange function

Tags: javascript, html

Thank you in advance or any help you can offer. I am building a menu with selection and options. After a chapter is selected, it will display the page options available. However, I would like it to default to showing the chapter one pages when the website first loads, instead of showing nothing. I can't seem to figure this one out. The code I have is as follows:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Chapter").onload = function () {
    if (this[this.selectedIndex].value === "1") {
    document.getElementById("c1").className = "show";
    }
};
</script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("Chapter").onchange = function () {
    if (this[this.selectedIndex].value === "1") {
    document.getElementById("c1").className = "show";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("c1").className = "";
    }
    if (this[this.selectedIndex].value === "2") {
        document.getElementById("c2").className = "show";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("c2").className = "";
    }
};
</script>
```

The onload code currently does nothing, but the onchange works as anticipated.

Thank you so much for your time.

Edit:
The HTML example is as follows:

```
<div class="jump-options text-center">
    QUICK JUMP: CHAPTER 
        <select id="Chapter">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
        </select> PAGE 
        <select id="c1" name="Page">
            <option value="1p0">0</option>
            <option value="1p1">1</option>
            <option value="1p2">2</option>
            <option value="1p3">3</option>
            <option value="1p4">4</option>
            <option value="1p5">5</option>
        </select>
        <select id="c2" name="Page">
            <option value="2p0">0</option>
            <option value="2p1">1</option>
            <option value="2p2">2</option>
            <option value="2p3">3</option>
            <option value="2p4">4</option>
            <option value="2p5">5</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What sort of element is `#Chapter`? I thought the `load` event was only for window (and maybe window-like) elements, but certainly not `<select>`s

Comment: FYI, you can just use `this.value` instead of `this[this.selectedIndex].value`.

Comment: Couldn't you omit the nested `onload`, and simply show the first chapter on page load?

Comment: I have edited to attach an HTML example. omitting the onload still leaves the page selection blank to start.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, I have made the change to clean up the code a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most DOM elements don't have `onload` events. This event only fires on elements that need to get their contents from external sources, like images and iframes.

You don't want to assign an `onload` handler, what you want to do is trigger the `change` event on `#Chapter`.

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Chapter").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
}
```

Comment: You are a blessing, thank you! It works as needed. :)